# Call method after counter cache is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way in Rails to call a function whenever counter cache is updated?

Comment: No. Are you triggering the counter cache update within the app, or is it a DB-level update?

Comment: counter cache update within the app using `:counter_cache => true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do that out of the box.  You could probably make a Gem that added that functionality without too much trouble.  It might be easier update the counter manually from an after_create and after_destroy callbacks, which could also execute any other code you need.

E.g.:

```
class Parent
  has_many :kids
  # The parents table has a `kids_counter` column which acts as a counter cache.
end

class Kid
  belongs_to :parent
  after_create :hello
  after_destroy :goodbye

  def hello
    Parent.increment_counter(:kids_counter, parent_id)
    # Execute anything else you need here.
  end

  def goodbye
    Parent.decrement_counter(:kids_counter, parent_id)
    # Execute anything else you need here.
  end
end
```